# Query regarding main() of GRUB

Tags: c, fopen, grub

Below is the code of main() of grub. Here I want to know about this line:

file = fopen(arg_v[1], "rb");

Here which file fopen is opening? What file this arg v[1] is pointing to?

```
int main(unsigned arg_c, char *arg_v[])    
{    
    FILE *file;    

    if(arg_c < 2)    
    {    
        printf("Checks if file is Multiboot compatible\n");    
        return 1;    
    }    
    file = fopen(arg_v[1], "rb");    
    if(file == NULL)    
    {    
        printf("Can't open file '%s'\n", arg_v[1]);    
        return 2;    
    }    
    check_multiboot(arg_v[1], file);    
    fclose(file);    
    return 0;    
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you call your program with

```
program arg1 arg2.txt 65
```

`argv[1]` is a pointer to `"arg1"`; `argv[2]` is a pointer to `"arg2.txt"`, `argv[3]` is a pointer to `"65"`, `argv[4]` is NULL

*argv[0] either points to `"program"` or to `""` if the OS and/or Library and/or startup code cannot identify the name used to call the binary executable*

In your specific case, the program tries to open a file, whose name is provided in the first argument to the program, in read binary mode.

Comment: The usual names of the variables are `argc` and `argv`. **There is nothing wrong about giving them other names**, it just makes it unusual *and unusual is not good*

Answer (score 1):

`arg_v` is a pointer to an array of pointers to strings passed to the program when main is invoked. `arg_v[1]` is hence a pointer to the first string passed to the program when it is invoked (even though the array starts at 0; the 0'th element is the program name itself).

**Edit:** So to be concrete, if the above is the main function of an executable invoked as `grub foo bar`, then `arg_v[0]` points to the string "grub" and `arg_v[1]` points to "foo". Hence the `fopen` call will try to open a file named "foo".